# Mongoosastic parameter es_copy_to

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am trying to resolve the issue of es_index: 'not_analyzed' not working (specified here: https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/76), by setting es_copy_to on model schema.

Do you know if mongoosastic (v. 2.x) supports this parameter, because it has no effect. I also tried multi_fields property but aggregations on elasticsearch cannot use this property.